# PgBouncer log management

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

My pgbouncer.log grows endlessly.

How do I enable filename rollover or limit the logfile size for pgbouncer on Ubuntu?

Comment: I remember that we used `rotate` on Linux to do that. (rotate by date & size).

Comment: @LuanHuynh: did you specify that in `pgbouncer.ini` or something? Would appreciate the details.

Comment: Over two years ago, we didn't use `pgbouncer.ini` to rotate logs because `pgBouncer` didn't support rotate logs (as `PostgreSQL`). That's why we had to use `rotate log of Linux`. In terms of `rotate log Ubuntu`, in fact, I didn't remember in details, however, please review https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10 , I think that web can help you.

Comment: Well, I think you can read this blog "http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-rotate-pgbouncer-logs-in.html".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now, [pgBouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/) **doesn't support rotate log**. Hence, you have to do it by yourself.

You can refer to sites below:

[How to rotate PgBouncer logs in Linux/Windows ?](http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-rotate-pgbouncer-logs-in.html)

[How To Manage Log Files With Logrotate On Ubuntu 12.10](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: I used `logrotate` to take care of it. But there's still a problem, perhaps you can help? After changing the desired logging level to `size 100M`, I forced logrotate via `logrotate -f`. As a result of that, I'm seeing: **error writing to /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log.1: No data available**. I.e log rotation has failed! When I do `tail -f pgbouncer.log`, I see a ton of log lines being generated in real time, so logging is still going on, but logrotation thinks there's `no data available`. What to do!?

Comment: Should I create an empty `pgbouncer.log.1` and retry?

Comment: How about your `pgbouncer.log` configuration file? (http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) . Please test before applying to production env.

Comment: In `pgbouncer.ini` (the configuration file), I can only configure the location of the log files, not their rotation credentials.

Comment: `pgbouncer.log` as this blog: http://raghavt.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-rotate-pgbouncer-logs-in.html. it is not `pgbouncer.ini`